# Best practices for setting up catkin_make install for python nodes

Tags: ros, python, catkin, best-practices, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently updating my code from rosbuild to catkin as I switch from Fuerte to Groovy.

Current setup: Ubuntu 12.04, Groovy

I am looking for best practices for packages with python nodes and libraries.

This is my current file structure:

```
/groovy-workspace
    /build
    /devel
    /install
    /src
       /my_meta_pkg
           /my_pkg_A
           /my_pkg B
           /my_pkg_etc...
```

Under /my_pkg_A:

```
/scripts
    my_node.py
    my_API.py (my_node imports my_API)
    __init__.py
setup.py
__init__.py
package.xml
CMakeLists.txt
```

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['my_pkg_A'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_pkg_A)

# Load catkin and all dependencies required for this package
set(CATKIN_DEPS std_msgs geometry_msgs rospy)
set(SYS_DEPS python-serial python-sys)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${CATKIN_DEPS})

# Install python scripts using distutils
catkin_python_setup()

catkin_package(
    DEPENDS ${SYS_DEPS}
    CATKIN_DEPENDS ${CATKIN_DEPS}
)

install(PROGRAMS scripts/my_node.py scripts/my_API.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION}
)
```

When I run

```
catkin_make install
```

in /groovy-workspace, it fails during the make sequence with the error

```
error: package directory 'src/my_pkg_A' does not exist
```

I have deduced that it is looking for the python scripts in the python workspace

```
/groovy-workspace/src/my_meta_pkg/my_pkg_A/src/my_pkg_A
```

Would it be best practice to create this directory and move my_node.py, my_API.py, and **init**.py to this directory? Or should I change setup.py to look at /scripts and what would be the best way to do this? Or is there a different way everything should be structured to follow ROS best practices?

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60707/best-practices-for-setting-up-catkin_make-install-for-python-nodes/) by [Brendan Andrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/4682/brendan-andrade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `setup.py` is setup to look for the API in `src`, if you want it to look in `scripts` then change it to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['my_pkg_A'],
    package_dir={'': 'scripts'}
)

setup(**d)
```

It would be best practice, however, to separate your API and scripts into different folders and the `src` folder is a good place to place your API files.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brendan Andrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/4682/brendan-andrade/) on 2013-04-15**:
I made this change and it returns the error:error: package directory 'scripts/my_pkg_A' does not exist. Should there be a folder /my_pkg_A/scripts/my_pkg_A? Is that where I should place my_node.py? Would this result in being able to use rosrun my_pkg_A my_node.py after sourcing the install setup?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-15**:
So, in python the "name" of your API (package) is the name of the folder containing the **init**.py, so yeah you probably want a sub folder for `src` which is the name of your package.

**Comment by [Brendan Andrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/4682/brendan-andrade/) on 2013-04-15**:
Would that be considered "best practice" for ROS packages with python nodes?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-15**:
Probably so, rosbuild could handle scripts directly under src/, but catkin is not completely compatible in that respect.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2016-11-23**:
how about adding srv and msg files... how should they be imported?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-11-23**:
http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_module_dependencies.html